# VBA Excel Sub runs really slow

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write this Sub, which updates a table of a (known) certain amount of columns but a uncertain amount of rows. I have values in the last row of the table and in the first column of the table which i need for the calculation. This is my code so far: 
(It works just runs really slow)

```
Sub updateMySheets()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim x, y As Integer

'Looks dynamically for the largest row & column index
numrows = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
numcols = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count

Range("C2").Select

Dim discount, margin As Double

For x = 1 To numrows - 1

  discount = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
  For y = 1 To numcols

    margin = ActiveCell.Offset(numrows - x, y - 1).Value

    If margin - discount <= 0.0001 Then

        'Hier noch ggf. die Cell farbig anpassen
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, y - 1).Value = ""

    Else

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, y - 1).Value = discount / (margin - discount)

    End If

Next

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True  
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve with this code?  It might be easier for us than trying to read your code.

Comment: The way your nested `For` loops are set up, this process is performing an action on every cell in the used range of your workbook. You may be able to optimize by being more selective over which cells you actually need to perform calculations and modifications to. The other thing that may help with speed would be using `ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Activate` instead of `ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select`. I have found that "selecting" things in Excel VBA is slower than "activating" them (I have no idea why).

Comment: In the first column are potential price decreases and in the last row are margins of certain products. What i want to calculate are the increases in volume which need to be achieved in order to maintain a certain margin. The formulas is only a rule of thumb and not exact. but it is enough for my purpose.

Comment: How many rows and how many columns to do you typically have?

Comment: @JoeMalpass I need the two for loops because I want to update every entry in the matrix. I will definitely try the activate suggestion!

Comment: @GisMofx exactly 10 columns and about 13 rows...

Comment: That's not a lot of cells. Seems like that should only take a second do accomplish. You should get rid of the select and calls to active cell. That's calls to using the UI. You should directly get the cell values.

Comment: Selecting or activating _anything_ in VBA takes more time to process - but the good news is - there isn't any need to select or activate anything in VBA. You can access an objects methods and properties directly without making it the selection.

Comment: With so few rows and columns, there must be an awful lot of calculation of spreadsheet formulas going on if you can even notice the execution time. In addition to getting rid of selection, you could look at turning automatic calculation and screen updating off at the beginning of the sub and then turning it back on at the end.

Comment: @JohnColeman - he's already doing that.

Comment: @JoeMalpass I see -- then it is really hard to tell what is causing time to be an issue. Maybe `numrows` and `numcols` are larger than 13 and 10, despite OP's intention. Maybe they should try `Debug.Print numrows`, etc.

Comment: This should be in **Code Review** : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba

Comment: @R3uK I was just telling the VBA Code Reviewers that... http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24520843#24520843

Comment: @Chrismas007 : Great, I tried to flag it, but you cannot choose the SE site on which you think the post should be, you just have a list of 4 or 5 sites... Might be a good functionality proposal on Meta! ;)

Comment: @R3uk I'm not sure CR is 100% out of Beta yet (full site design).  I believe there has already been a Meta proposal to add CR to the migration flag list. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276017/add-code-review-to-belongs-on-another-site-now-that-the-site-has-graduated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I've marked my comments with `'//` and commented out your existing code with standard `'`

```
Sub MM()

'// You can use "," to Dim multiple variables but you still
'// need to declare the data type otherwise it will default
'// to type "Variant" which can cause issues later in your code.
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
Dim discount As Double, margin As Double

''Looks dynamically for the largest row & column index
'numrows = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Rows.count
'numcols = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlToRight)).Columns.count

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

With sh
    '// Get the row number of the last row in C and minus 1 for the header.
    numRows = .Cells(.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row - 1

    '// Same logic for the columns
    numCols = .Cells(2, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1

    '// Never need to ".Select" anything
    'Range("C2").Select

    'Dim discount, margin As Double (See first comment)

    For x = 1 To numRows - 1

      '// Just use x to determine the row number.
      'discount = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).value
      discount = .Cells(x + 1, 2).value

        For y = 1 To numCols
            margin = .Cells(x + 1, 3).Offset(numRows - x, y - 1).value

            If margin - discount <= 0.0001 Then
                .Cells(x + 1, 3).Offset(0, y - 1).value = ""
            Else
                .Cells(x + 1, 3).Offset(0, y - 1).value = discount / (margin - discount)
            End If
        Next

    Next

End With

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this seemed to do the trick! I should really look into this whole "not using select/activate"-thing.Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped.

Comment: I need to run this sub on 8 different worksheets. how can i do this without activating each sheet?

Comment: See edit above. (really, that's a different question and should be a new post - but I'm feeling nice, so merry Christmas :) )

Comment: I know I know ;D Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way. Your code did speed it up by a bunch, but for what ever reason, the real problem was that I had the columns and rows marked as a table. as soon as I removed the formatting the sub (also mine) was done instantly!

Comment: formatting in VBA _alwayssssss_ takes forever - best to just leave formatting alone where possible.